# Symmetric matrices and commutivity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been going through a research problem statement provided by my Professor. The problem is about estimating the difference between gaussian graph models from their precision matrices. In order to estimate the difference, some assumptions are made. The following are the assumptions

1. $A$ is symmetric
2. $B^2$ is diagonal
3. $AB$ is symmetric

Right after this, it is pointed out that $AB$ commutes ($AB = BA$). I know that if two matrices are symmetric and their product is symmetric then the product commutes. But here $B^2$ is diagonal. So how does $AB$ commute?

Comment: The second point is "$B^2$ is diagonal", or "$B$ is diagonal" ? And also, the sentence "$B$ is just diagonal not symmetric" is quite weird...

Comment: Diagonal $\;\implies\;$  Symmetric ...

Comment: $B^2$ is diagonal. If $B^2$ is diagonal, one cannot be sure that $B$ is diagonal hence symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. Consider
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $A$ is symmetric, $B^2=I$ is diagonal, and
$$AB = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

is symmetric, but
$$BA= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -3 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \neq AB$$

so $A$ and $B$ don't commute.

Comment: How did you approach thinking of a counter-example?

Comment: I took for $B$ the easiest non-diagonal matrix I know such that $B^2=I$, and I wrote $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c 
\end{pmatrix}$$
and then, just computed all the products to find a good $A$.